# RMarkdown error with melt() function

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a file word starting from a program that on console perfectly works.

The problem is that when it reaches a function that uses `melt()` it generates an error

> cannot find melt function

and stops compiling the code.

The package `reshape` is installed, and I tried to rerun the code without using markdown and it doesn't generate any error.
Is possible that RMarkdown doesn't support `melt()` function?

Comment: No, it is not at all possible that R Markdown doesn't support using valid functions.

Comment: Did you load `reshape` package inside R markdown using `library()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a package is not enough — you need to load it. It’s possible that it works in your console because it was still loaded from before, or because you installed it in the current session.

To use the package, you need to add the following into your (R Markdown) code, before using any of its functions:

```
library(reshape)
```

Alternatively, you can just prefix all its functions with `reshape::`. So, instead of calling `melt`, you’d call `reshape::melt`. That’s less commonly done but there’s nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I already loaded the package, sorry for not saying it. If I run the normal code everything works perfectly, the error comes out just when i use markdown

Comment: @juse: as Konrad said, you need to have the `library(reshape)` call _in the R markdown file_, *not* just in the main RStudio (i.e. global) environment.

Answer (score 0):

Load the package inside R markdown. Loading the package outside R markdown is not enough. The loading of package should be inside R chunk in R markdown.

````
  ```{r}
  library(reshape)
  melt(iris)
  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and finally solved it. It was caused by setting eval=FALSE inside the code chunk that loaded the libraries in my Markdown document, including reshape2. When I removed that option, it finally worked:

`{r setoptions, ***eval=FALSE***}
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)`